# Toggleclass on several div ids/classes in Jquery + Jquery-Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have one little question towards the toggleclass function of the Jquery library. I am currently working on a jquery-mobile app with lists and content articles. Within this articles i want to implement a "nightmode". After touching the nightmode button every article, with the same class but a !!different id!! should toggle its class.

I will show you my article html-structure, my css and my jQuery script for it.

So this is my Code-Structure:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#nightmode_article1').click(function(){
    $('#article1').toggleClass('night');
});

$('#nightmode_article2').click(function(){
    $('#article2').toggleClass('night');
});


});
```

```css
 .day {
  background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
 background-repeat:repeat;       
    text-align: center;
}

.night {
 background-image: url(images/background-night.jpg);
 background-repeat:repeat;      
 text-align: center;
 color: #F0F0F0;
 text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
    <div data-role="page" id="article1" class="day"> 
    <header data-role="header">
    <button id="nightmode_article1"><img src="images/night-icon.png" /></button>
    <h1>Article1</h1>
    </header>
    <article data-role="content">

    </article>
    <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <nav data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-icon="back">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </footer>
    </div> 

    <div data-role="page" id="article2" class="day"> 
    <header data-role="header">
    <button id="nightmode_article2"><img src="images/night-icon.png" /></button>
    <h1>Article1</h1>
    </header>
    <article data-role="content">

    </article>
    <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <nav data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-icon="back">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Is there any possibility not to make different buttons for every article? I want to toggle the class in every article (in more then one article id) just by touching/pushing one button with one id.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of an ID on the night mode buttons, assign all of them the same class, e.g.:

```
<button class="nightModeButton"><img src="images/night-icon.png" /></button>
```

Then add a click handler for that class so clicking any of the night mode buttons runs the same code:

```
$('.nightModeButton').click(function(){
    $('[data-role="page"]').toggleClass('night');
});
```

In the handler, toggle the night class on all articles by using the `$('[data-role="page"]')` selector. Assuming all your articles are within the page like your example code, they will all be updated.

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/xquw98q6/)**

If you are dynamically injecting the articles, you will need to save the current mode and set the class for the incoming page.

Comment: Hey mate. Thank you very much. That helped me a lot and it works :-) So it seems the best solution is the easiest one and sometimes you just cant see it :-)

Comment: Changing ID into Class for a Button and correcting the syntax solved my problem :-)